# post method in express.js not working for BMI calculator

Tags: javascript, express, post

i am creating a simple BMI calculator app for JavaScript practice, which takes two inputs weight and height. but after providing inputs and submitting the web page doesn't show calculated BMI. also in devtools network it shows request method get. i have attached the related code. please help!!

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // for input data coming from html form

// home route for calculator
 app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
     res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");  //sending index.html as a response using res.sendFile method 
 })

 //processing post request for calculator
 app.post("/", (req, res)=>{
    var num1 =Number(req.body.num1);
    var num2 =Number(req.body.num2);
    var total = num1 + num2;
    res.send(`<h1>the total is ${total}</h1>`);
 })


 // route for get request for bmicalculator
 app.get("/bmicalculator", function(req, res){
     res.sendFile(__dirname+"/BMIcalculator.html");
 })

// processing post request and returning calculated BMI
app.post("/bmicalculator", function(req, res){
    var weight = parseFloat(req.body.weight);
    var height = parseFloat(req.body.height);
    var BMI = weight / Math.pow(height, 2);
    console.log(BMI);
    res.send(BMI);
})

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("server is listening at port 3000");
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BMI calculator</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: darkkhaki;">
    <h1>calculate your BMI</h1>
    <form action="/bmicalculator" method="post"></form>
    <input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="enter your weight">
    <input type="text" name="height" placeholder="enter your height in meters">
    <button type="submit" name="Submit">calculate BMI</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uh u didn't attack the code.. Pls attach it

Comment: *attached* ... try *pasting* the code, it works well

Comment: i just pasted my code @Bravo

Comment: i just did @ArchitGargi

Comment: I'm surprised you get any sort of request happening, since your form has no content `<form action="/bmicalculator" method="post"></form>` - you need those inputs **inside** the form

Comment: @Bravo i don't understand what you mean by having no content in the form??

Comment: your form element has no content ... `<form action="/bmicalculator" method="post">` nothing here `</form>`

Comment: @Bravo ...thanks man got it..its my silly mistake  i have been grinding over this since morning..i forgot to put those input tags inside form tag..thanks man..

Answer (score -1):

Keep your INPUT tags inside FORM tag then only request went to server and you will receive response back.